# Efficiently matching empty elements of arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, element

I have two arrays, $A and $B. Both arrays have the same length, but array $A will always either have the same number of non-empty elements as $B or it will have less non-empty elements than $B.

So if,

```
$B = array("john","adams","sandwich");
```

then $A could either be,

```
$A = array("bacon","ham","juice");
```

or it could be,

```
$A = array("bacon","","");
```

I'm trying to match the empty elements of $B to $A. So I can get,

```
$B = array("john","","");
```

I'm currently doing it through the following code:

```
$q = count($A) - 1;
$l = count($A) - count(array_filter($A));
$i = 1;
while($i <= $l){
    $B[$q] = "";
    $i++;
    $q--;
}
```

But this method is extremely slow and might cause problems considering that I'm going to be doing it several times. Do you guys have any suggestions on how to do this more efficiently? The arrays will never be larger than 20 elements, but this is still time consuming for some reason.

Comment: are the non-empty elements always going to be at the beginning of the array?

Comment: Yes, the non-empty elements will always be in the beginning.

Comment: why use `$i, $l, $q` when you can do fine with only one of them ? and second, looping till you reach `$l` won't "match" between the elements of the array

Comment: $q is to find the length of the array (this value will change at each script execution). $l is to find how many of those are empty which basically tells me how many I need to remove. And I'm just using $i as a counter. I've also tried this using a foreach() method without using any indices, but that seems to be even slower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code will work in all cases, whether empty values are on any position in array:

```
$A = array('a', 'b', 'c');
$B = array('', 'ab', 'zx');
$B = array_filter($B, 'strlen');
$B = array_filter($A, 'customfun');
print_r($B);
exit;
function customfun($param) {
    global $A;
    global $B;
    $key = array_search($param, array_values($A));
    if(isset($B[$key])) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this..

```
$c=array_diff($a,$b);
foreach($c as $key=>$val){
if($val=="")
    $b[$key]="";
}
```

Hope it works ...

Answer (score 1):

Another easy way is to (re)place the empty items from `$A` into `$B`.

```
$B = array_replace($B, preg_grep('/^$/D', $A));
```

Answer (score 0):

If understand your problem correctly, then you might be looking for this:

```
$x = count(array_filter($A))
$B = array_merge(array_slice($B,0,$x), array_fill(0,count($B)-$x,""))
```

or do

```
foreach($B as $i => &$v)
    if($A[$i] == "")
        $v = ""
```

Comment: The first method works great, but unfortunately I'm going to run into issues when there are no non-empty elements. And the second method I've tried already, but seems to be slower than running the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
//test.php
$b = array("john","adams","sandwich");
$a = array("bacon","","");

$length = count($a);

for($lcv = 0; $lcv < $length; ++$lcv)
{
    if($a[$lcv] == "")
    {
        $b[$lcv] = "";
    } 
}

?>
```

like this?

Answer (score 0):

```
function getArr($b,$a)
{
    if($a === '')
    {
        return '';
    }
    return $b;
}
$B = array("john","adams","sandwich");
$A = array("bacon","","");
print_r($A);
$B = array_map('getArr',$B,$A);
print_r($B);
```